# When adding enableCompression configuration to sessionpool in Apache IoTDB, why did the server failed to be connected?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb

We add a compression configuration in sessionpool of Apache IoTDB, which is written as `iotDBProperties.enableCompression` to adjust if the data needs to be compressed using the additional compression algorithm we wrote.
However, the system reported `Fail to reconnect to server. Please check server status.xxx:6667`. When we removed this configuration, the system can be normally operated. Why did this happened? Are there any other configuration backstage that I also need to change to execute the configuration successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable the compression mechanism you added, you need to modify the configuration of Apache IoTDB and restart the service. The parameters of configuration includes `dn_rpc_thrift compression_enable` and `cn_rpc_thrift_compression enable`, which means whether to enable thrift's compression mechanism, and `dn_rpc_advanced_compression_enable`, and `cn_rpc_advanced compression enable`, which means whether to enable thrift's custom compression mechanism. However, modifications are generally not recommended since it may cause the whole system to be shutdown. You can decide if you really need to change the compression.